# JQuery (Javascript) Error TimeOut después de un tiempo de ejecutar un script en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error después de 5 min de ejecutarse un script en PHP:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Pero hay algo curioso que no entiendo, la configuración de php es la siguiente:
mi servidor, indica que tiene dos archivos php.ini en estas direcciones:

```
/etc/php/7.4/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

ambos archivos tienen esta variable configurada:

```
max_execution_time = 900
```

(900segundos = 15minutos)
ya revise si existe un archivo local al sitio web y no hay mas configuraciones que puedan afectar esa variable ni siquiera el .htaccess

el script que ejecuto es uno que genera un archivo zip para posteriormente ser descargado, el detalle esta en que cuando el zip a generar es muy grande el tiempo no alcanza para terminarlo.

Aquí es donde viene lo curioso, a pesar de que recibo el mensaje de error anteriormente mostrado, después de 5 minutos de ejecutar estas instrucciones en javascript:

```
$.post(url,data,function(result){
    $(".all-gen-trans").remove();
    let file = zipName + ".zip";
    // Download process
}).fail(function(){
    $(".all-gen-trans").remove();
    alert("Something went wrong");
});
```

el archivo zip se sigue construyendo, lo se porque al inspeccionar la carpeta temporal que tengo asignada para esos archivos, el archivo sigue creciendo cada que hago un refresh sobre esa carpeta, incluso he detectado de que después de 15 min sigue construyéndose. Por lo que por esa situación no se si sea algo del lado del cliente, pero no se que podría ser.

La única configuración en php con algo que represente esos 5 min, es esta variable:

```
; TTL for user-defined php.ini files (time-to-live) in seconds. Default is 300 seconds (5 minutes)
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300
```

a pesar de estar comentada su valor por defecto son esos 300s, pero la verdad no la he tocado porque no se para que sirve y si puede llevar a beneficiarme o afectarme.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo cuál es el problema. ¿Has pensando en sólo verificar que el archivo está construido correctamente para entonces traerlo desde el cliente?

Comment: El detalle esta en que al recibir la respuesta de error, el cliente ejecuta la parte del fail() y termina el proceso, entonces ya no hay manera de saber cuando terminara de construirse el zip porque el cliente ya recibió una supuesta respuesta de error y ya terminó de "escuchar". Podría poner un timer para verificar cada x tiempo, pero no creo que sea lo mas eficiente o correcto.

Comment: Entiendo, pero yo me refiero a verificar en el servidor si el archivo es correcto, si no lo es, mandas una respuesta en `result` diciendo que el archivo no está listo (en ese caso no entrará en el fail) y vuelves a reprogramar para verificar dentro de X minutos, así, mientras el archivo no sea correcto (verificado en el servidor) no se intentará obtener erróneamente. Lo que ocurre aquí es una implementación de código sin manejo adecuado de errores.

Comment: O, si quieres algo más moderno, puedes ir pensando en [`Server-sent Events`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html), que permite enviar notificaciones al cliente desde el servidor, así, cuando el archivo esté listo notificas al cliente para que éste lo recupere.

Comment: Voy a darle una revisada a "Server sent" gracias, aun así me gustaría entender porque javascript recibe un error timeout aun cuando en php se sigue ejecutando el script, o al menos eso aparenta.

Comment: El timeout está ocurriendo en el servidor, probablemente porque el proceso de crear el `.zip` allí está tardando más de lo normal. Entonces tienes que revisar en servidor para ver si hay algo que optimizar. No siempre es una cuestión de memoria, sino de que el código tarda en algún punto, pensemos en consultas a bases de datos por ejemplo cuyos datos no están optimizados, o en código mal escrito (bucles indefinidos por ejemplo), o en que se están intentando procesar demasiados datos. En procesos costosos sí o sí (por ejemplo por ser mucho contenido) hay que plantearse cambiar de estrategia ...

Comment: ... ya sea procesando el contenido por lotes, ya sea ejecutando el proceso (en este caso la creación del `.zip`) a un nivel más bajo, donde funcionaría más rápido, sin intermediarios, escribiendo un script en la misma consola.

Comment: Tienes muchas ideas, yo la verdad aun soy algo nuevo en php a pesar de tener un par de años programando en él. ¿Que me recomiendas entonces para cambiar el script que genera el zip? estuve leyendo un poco de script en Bash cuando mencionaste hacerlo a niveles bajos.

Comment: Cuando hablaba de hacerlo a un más bajo nivel me refería precisamente a esa posibilidad (un script en bash que cree el `.zip`). Una estrategia interesante podría ser crear el archivo en ese entorno y mandarlo por correo electrónico o simplemente colocarlo en una carpeta y notificar al cliente de algún modo, eso ya depende de tu contexto y de lo que se te esté requiriendo para este programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vi algo de esto en otra consulta, si el archivo tarda tanto en crearse lo mejor es asignarlo a un comando [bash un simple](https://desarrolloweb.com/faq/compresion-descompresion-zip-comandos)

```
  <?php
$ejemplo= system('zip -q -r destino_ID_identificativo.zip carpeta_a_comprimir > /dev/null &');
?>
```

usando [system](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.system.php)

cuando usas el /dev/null & le dices al comando que se ejecute en segundo plano, esto genera un PID o id de proceso que esta ejecutándose

por ejemplo 12345
Un truco para buscar el PID y si esta activo es el ID_identificativo que agregaste al archivo, con esto puedes generar un nuevo archivo php para chequear ejemplo

```
<?php
exec('ps -x | grep zip',$salida,$ret);
echo "\n";
$id="ID_identificativo";
$encontrado=false;
foreach ($salida as $v) {
    if(strstr($v,$id)){
        $encontrado=true;
        break;
    }
 }
if($encontrado){
    echo "en proceso";
}else{
    echo "archivo terminado";
}
echo "\n";
?>
```

con eso puedes parsear los datos en php para verificar si el proceso esta activo, si termino puedes hacer una salida de al navegador (echo) que atraves de ajax puedes decirle al usuario, esta listo su archivo.
hay muchas formas de hacerlo y poder informar al usuario, solo describo una de ellas.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, estoy haciendo algunas pruebas, ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre usar exec o system para la creación del zip? mas haya de la salida supongo.

Comment: Los únicos cambios que hice fue agregar un `cd /folder;` al script para que no me generara una cadena grande de carpetas en el zip antes de la carpeta objetivo y en lugar de revisar los procesos zip del servidor, agregue un registro a un base de datos que después consulto.