# Ejecutar PHP en segundo plano, crear LOG

Tags: php

quiero desde PHP llamar otro archivo PHP en segundo plano ya que tarda unos 15 minutos en ejecutarse.

Lo hago con los comandos:

```
$command = 'php cargar_datos.php "2022-06-13" "2022-06-18"';
pclose(popen($command, 'r'));
```

No devuelve ningun error, pero no finaliza nunca la ejecución.

En cambio si voy desde el terminal y ejecuto directamente el PHP, si que funciona sin problemas

```
php cargar_datos.php "2022-06-13" "2022-06-18"
```

Hay alguna forma de guardar un LOG o algo para ver donde se me pierde el programa con el popen?

Gracias

Comment: Quieres decir... ¿se inicia el proceso pero no se cierra? (Cuando lo haces con `popen` y `pclose`)

Comment: Si, y no realiza lo que tiene que hacer el programa, consulta a una BBDD, modificar los datos y guardarlos en otra BBDD

Comment: esta seguro que entiendes funcionamiento de popen te dejo el manual https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.popen.php lo que debes utilizar es exec() te dejo el manual tambien https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

te dejo la referencia a una respueta muy silimar
usamos ejecucion en segundo plano para poder liberar el proceso actual y luego se revisa con un script para corroborar si termino o no:
[JQuery (Javascript) Error TimeOut después de un tiempo de ejecutar un script en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537888/jquery-javascript-error-timeout-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-tiempo-de-ejecutar-un-script-en/538124#538124)

ejemplo con tu codigo

```
<?php
$command = 'php cargar_datos.php "2022-06-13" "2022-06-18"';
$ejemplo= system($command.' > /dev/null &');
?>
```

esto generaŕa un proceso en segundo plano y en la referencia tienes como examinarlo.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes usar el exec o shell_exec que proporciona php, aquí tienes la documentación

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php

```php
$output = shell_exec('ls');
```

Comment: Con esta función se espera a que termine la ejecución (los 15 min) y dará error. POr eso usi el POPEN, para que lo ejecute en segundo plano y no espere a que finalize