# Como evitar que muera la conexión del navegador usando los bufer de salida al generar un excel con php

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Estoy intentando generar un excel demasiado grande pero me saca error 504 y no es por memoria si no por tiempo de espera del navegador intente quitarle este limite pero segui ocurriendo intente usar las funciones de ob_start(); de php y ya dejo de salir el 504 pero ya luego no me descarga el excel si no que me muestra el binario en pantalla intente cambiarle los header pero no funciono este es mi código:

```
ob_start();

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Nombre');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Edad');

$datos_prueba = array(
    array('Alice', 28),
    array('Bob', 32),
    array('Charlie', 22),
);

$row = 2; 
foreach ($datos_prueba as $datos) {
    echo str_pad(' ', 4096);
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    usleep(100);

    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $datos[0]);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $datos[1]);
    $row++;
}

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="informe.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

ob_clean();

$writer->save('php://output');

ob_end_flush();
```

Nota: en el for yo tengo muchísimos más datos que hacen que salga el 504 pero para que sea más entendible les pongo el ejemplo con solo 3 datos.

Comment: Busca información sobre yield e iteradores en PHP. Hay un ejemplo en el manual que puede ayudarte, creo que es para leer un CSV pero se puede aplicar al lector de bbdd

Comment: @Jakala Tienes algún link en especifico que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: @JuanRincon lo mas recomendable es que uses un proceso diferido cuando el tiempo es excesivo, apache esta echo para esponder rapido pero cuando el codigo se queda colgado mas de 30 segundos este se cae o dependiendo de tu configuracion, yo te recomendaria que generes una cola de generacion y que sea por cron job, asi no dejas colgada en espera la interacion del usuario, cuando este listo le descargas con ajax.

Comment: @John aplica también para nginx?, nginx es el que uso

Comment: es simple y asi es como trabajan google drive y otros proovedores de archivos, por eso siempre muestran un proceso y despues te avisan para descargar, asi no colapsan la conexión del usuario. ahora si es por CLI es mucho mejor por que puedes acelerar el trabajo, lo otro seria optimizar la generacion lo mas posible, por ejemplo solicitar a la BD solo la informacion que vas a usar y usar POO para generar el excel. con php8 es mas rapido y la misma libreria PhpOffice puede generar en un a carpeta temporal hasta que el usuario descarge

Comment: @JuanRincon si nginx tambien usa tiempos de conexion

Comment: @JuanRincon mira echa un vistaso a este tema que abarco algo parecido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537888/jquery-javascript-error-timeout-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-tiempo-de-ejecutar-un-script-en/538124#538124 alli el problema era que se demoraba mucho al crear el zip con php, lo cual es parecido, pero el truco es el mismo, haces correr un proceso por separado y consultas cada cierto tiempo si este termino, si ya termino le dices al navegador que descargue el archivo.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con John porque tuve el mismo problema de cierre de la conexión por inactividad. En mi caso era un envío de correos masivo para una newsletter. La solución fue copiar el código en un proceso separado (que es lo mismo que propone en la respuesta enlazada) de forma que la web solo devolviera un mensaje de que el envío se estaba procesando.